# python plt.bar concatenate error

Tags: python, matplotlib, concatenation

i have 2 lists and i want to put them together in a pyplot.bar

```
sorted_ratings2 = ['8,3','8,2','8,2','8,3','8,5','8,4','8,2','8,5', '8,2','8,2']

Year = ['1921','1925','1926','1927','1931','1931','1934','1936','1939','1939','1939']



plt.bar((Year), (sorted_ratings2)
plt.suptitle('Ratings based on years', fontsize=14)
plt.ylabel('Rating', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=12)  
plt.show()


Output: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

i try to plot with plt.bar but get this error.  what do i do wrong?

Comment: Your `bar` call is missing a closing bracket.

Comment: I suspect the quotes around your values. Try removing them in the "ratings" list...it's probably why the code thinks it's strings

Comment: Also whilst `8,3` is sometimes used (primarily on the continent) to denote a decimal number, it will only cause you problems in programming. You need to use 8.3.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/lines_bars_and_markers/barh_demo.html) is the link I used to figure it out

```
from matplotlib import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
sorted_ratings2 = [8.3, 8.2, 8.2, 8.3, 8.5, 8.4, 8.2, 8.5, 8.2, 8.2]

Years = ['1921', '1925', '1926', '1927', '1931', '1931', '1934', '1936', '1939', '1939']

x_pos = np.arange(len(Years))


plt.bar(x_pos, sorted_ratings2)
plt.suptitle('Ratings based on years', fontsize=14)
plt.xticks(x_pos, Years)
plt.ylabel('Rating', fontsize=12)
plt.xlabel('Year', fontsize=12)  
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: BTW, your two lists are different lengths - one is 10 items long and the other is 11.